# DISCORD.PY - Как добавить TimeStamp и аватарку отправившего сообщения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при написании команды *.say* отправлялось вместе с сообщением аватарку автора и время, когда отправлялось сообщение. Это как-то делается через `embed.add_author`. Мой код:

````
@commands.has_permissions( administrator = True ) 
async def say(ctx, *, content: str): 
    title, description= content.split('|') 
    embed = discord.Embed( 
        title=title,  
        description=description, 
        color=discord.Colour.dark_blue(), 
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Comment: Если вам что-то нужно объяснить, то просто напишите здесь. Я попытаюсь дополнить!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить время - параметр `timestamp`. В качестве значения указываем время создания текущего сообщения "`.say текст|текст`" - `ctx.message.created_at`

Добавить аватар можно через метод `set_image()` или `set_thumbnail()` класса `discord.Embed`. В данном случае он будет принимать значение `url`, куда мы передадим ссылку на аватар пользователя.

Разница в том, что `set_image()` добавляет большую картинку, а `set_thumbnail()` маленькую, справа сверху.

Какой нужен вам, выбирайте сами :)

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, content):
    title, description= content.split('|') 
    embed = discord.Embed( 
        title=title,  
        description=description, 
        color=discord.Colour.dark_blue(),
        timestamp=ctx.message.created_at
    )
    embed.set_image(url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Сейчас проверем...

Comment: Слушай, братан, а можно как-то сделать через ```embed.add_author```? Просто, мне нужно чтобы был ник автора и аватарка автора. Увы. А так все отлично!

Comment: Можно и через `set_author()`, вот документация: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.set_author